# Android: improving conversion speed of grayscale bitmap to monochromatic

Tags: android, kotlin, android-color

How can I improve the speed of the following process of conversion?

For grayscale bitmap of 384x524 pixels, this takes around 2,1 seconds on the target device.

```
fun convertToMonochromatic(bitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap {
    val result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, bitmap.config)

    for (row in 0 until bitmap.height) {
        for (col in 0 until bitmap.width) {
            val hsv = FloatArray(3)
            Color.colorToHSV(bitmap.getPixel(col, row), hsv)

            if (hsv[2] > 0.7f) {
                result.setPixel(col, row, Color.WHITE)
            } else {
                result.setPixel(col, row, Color.BLACK)
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Is there some "mass operation", transforming all the pixels at once directly based on the HSV and the Value particulary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this access, to iterate the pixels one by one, it seems the main time consuming part is the *colorToHSV* function. It computes more info, than the needed **Value**.

Description of the transform https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.html

After the following adjustion, the needed time for the given size, is reduced from 2,1 seconds to 0,1 second.

```
    fun convertToMonochromatic(bitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap {
        val result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, bitmap.config)

        val size = bitmap.width * bitmap.height
        val input = IntArray(size)
        val output = IntArray(size)

        bitmap.getPixels(input, 0, bitmap.width, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)

        var current = 0
        input.forEach {

            val red = it shr 16 and 0xFF
            val green = it shr 8 and 0xFF
            val blue = it and 0xFF

            val max = maxOf(red, green, blue)
            if (max > 175) {
                output[current++] = Color.WHITE
            } else {
                output[current++] = Color.BLACK
            }
        }

        result.setPixels(output, 0, bitmap.width, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)

        return result
    }
```

Comment: yeah wanted to notice about `Color` class operations however though it won't this bad. Good job man :)